# Riemann explicit formula for $\psi^*(x)$ in the region $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

**Is it possible to extend this Riemann explicit formula to interval $0\leq x\leq 1$?**
$$\psi^*(x)=x-\sum_{\rho} \frac {x^{\rho}}{\rho}-\frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)}$$

Sum over trivial zeros of zeta $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^{-2 n}}{-2 n}=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}\right)$ diverges for $|x|\leq 1$. So that is why the formula does not work in this region. But the rest of the formula is still meaningful also in this region, i.e. sum over non-trivial zeros does converge even for $0\leq x\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer is that $\psi(x) = 0$ for $x \le 1$, that's as dumb as that, even if there is more to say, revealing the point of the domain of convergence of Laplace/ Mellin transforms :

For every $s, \Re(s) \ne \Re(\rho)$

$$\frac{1}{s-\rho} = \int_0^\infty x^{-s-1}  x^\rho u_{\Re(s-\rho)}(x) dx, \qquad\qquad
u_a(x) = \begin{cases}1_{x > 1} \text{ if } a > 0, \\  - 1_{x < 1} \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
In the same way, the Riemann explicit formula (residue theorem + density of zeros, or Weierstrass factorization theorem for entire functions of order $\le 1$)

shows that for $s$ on a vertical strip with no zeros or poles
$$\frac{-1}{s}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \int_0^\infty x^{-s-1}\psi_{\Re(s)}(x)dx$$
Where 
$$\psi_c(x)= \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c +i\infty}\frac{-1}{s}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} x^s ds$$ $$=x^1 u_{c-1}(x)  -\sum_{\rho \text{ non-trivial}} \frac {x^{\rho}}{\rho}  u_{c-\Re(\rho)}(x)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {x^{-2k}}{-2k}  u_{c+2k}(x)-\frac{\zeta'(0)}{\zeta(0)} u_{c}(x)$$

Comment: We know that $\psi(x) = 0$ for $x \le 1$ just from definition of $\psi(x)$, without knowing Mellin inversion theorem. So you are trying to say, that inverse Mellin transfom says nothing about behavior of $\psi(x)$ for $x \le 1$ or that it says just that $\psi(x) = 0$ for $x \le 1$ and nothing more?

Comment: @azerbajdzan See how it works for $x^\rho 1_{x > 1}$ and $\frac{1}{s-\rho}$, domain of convergence, Mellin inversion, residue theorem.

Comment: I do not understand it. What has your function $\psi_c(x)$ with $c\le 1$ to do with the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$? For $c\le 1$ it does not converge to the second Chebyshev function.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Did you look carefuly at $x^\rho 1_{x > 1}$ and $\frac{1}{s-\rho }$ ? At first we have $\psi(x) = \sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n)$. Its Mellin transform is of the form $\frac{1}{s}(\frac{-F'(s)}{F(s)}+\frac{1}{s-1})$ with $F$ entire of order $\le 1$, thus the Mellin transform is a series of poles, which gives by Mellin inversion an explicit formula for $\psi(x)$ **as a series of $ x^\rho 1_{x > 1}$**. The $1_{x > 1}$ is perfectly natural in the context of Mellin transforms/Laplace/Fourier transforms and it becomes $-1_{x < 1}$ when changing the domain of convergence.

Comment: Yes I looked at $\frac{1}{s-\rho} = \int_0^\infty x^{-s-1}  x^\rho u_{\Re(s-\rho)}(x) dx$ and I agree it holds for every s but its inverse does not hold for $x\le 1$... same as with Riemann formula.

Comment: I mean $\frac{1}{2 \pi  i}\int_{c-i \infty }^{c+i \infty } \frac{x^s}{s-\rho} \, ds\neq x^r u_{c-\Re(\rho)}(x)$ for $x\le 1$.

Comment: Can you give me explicit values of $c$ and $\rho$ and $0\le x\le 1$ such that the formula in my previous comment holds?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Your previous comment is unclear. $\int_0^\infty x^{-s-1}x^\rho u_{\Re(s-\rho)} dx = \frac{1}{s-\rho}$ is true for every $s, \Re(s) \ne \Re(\rho)$ and $x^\rho u_{\Re(s-\rho)} = \frac{1}{2 \pi  i}\int_{c-i \infty }^{c+i \infty } \frac{1}{s-\rho} x^s ds$ is true for every $x > 0, c \ne \Re(\rho)$. Do you know how to use the Fourier inversion theorem to show this last statement ? And how to use the residue theorem ?

Comment: If $\Re(c-\rho)>0$ then $x^\rho u_{\Re(s-\rho)}(x)=0$ for $0<x<1$, but the integral of inverse transform is not zero.

Comment: @azerbajdzan It is not true. Show every step you are using for $c > \Re(\rho)$ to evaluate $\frac{1}{2 \pi  i}\int_{c-i \infty }^{c+i \infty } \frac{1}{s-\rho} x^s ds = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{c u}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_c(\omega) e^{i\omega u} d\omega$ where $f_c(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u c}e^{\rho u}1_{u > 0} e^{-i u \omega} d \omega$ is the Fourier transform of $e^{-uc}e^{\rho u} 1_{u > 0}$ and $u = \log x$.

Comment: Oh, I give up. I am going to accept your answer as correct. I believe you are right but I just do not understand it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @azerbajdzan ?? You need to study the Fourier inversion theorem and the residue theorem. Those are not trivial, but you can't avoid them. That's why I asked you to show what you already know. The point of your question is that $\psi(x) = x-\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log 2\pi$ is not true, everybody forget to mention it is $\psi(x) = (x-\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log 2\pi)1_{x > 1}$

Comment: $\psi(x) = (x-\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log 2\pi)1_{x > 1}$ That is exactly how I understood it. And my question was whether it can be extended to $0\le x\le 1$. And if I understand all your comments here correctly you are trying to say that all we can say about $\psi(x)$ when $0\le x\le 1$ is that $\psi(x)$=0. So that there does not exist some formula in form of infinite series like the one for $x>1$.

Comment: should be ..."infinite series over zeta zeros"

Comment: @azerbajdzan Mellin inversion with the residue theorem gives $\psi(x) = x1_{x > 1}-\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho 1_{x > 1}}{\rho}-\log 2\pi 1_{x > 1}$. The $1_{x > 1}$ isn't added by me, it appears during the calculus, we show $s\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is a series of poles $\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{1}{s-\rho}$ and Mellin inversion of $\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{1}{s-\rho}$ gives $\frac{x^\rho 1_{x > 1}}{\rho}$.

Comment: And switching $1_{x > 1}$ to $-1_{x < 1}$ is what happens when applying Mellin inversion to strips on the left of $\Re(s) = 1/2$. Only under the RH it makes sense to look at $x^{-1/2}\sum_\rho \frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}$ and $x^{1/2}\sum_\rho x^{\rho -1}$ with converges only in the sense of distibutions, see the Weil's explicit formula.

Comment: Thanks again, this explanation is satisfactory for me at the moment. Hope some day I will be able to understand it in more detail like you.

Comment: Search about the Fourier inversion theorem and then about the residue theorem applied to Mellin/Laplace inversion of $\frac{1}{s-\rho}$.

Comment: There is a similar explicit formula (that is, an explicit formula involving $\sum_{\rho}x^{\rho}/\rho$) for $0<x<1$. It can be found studying the sum $\sum_{n\leq1/x}\Lambda(n)/n$ with the same technique of the classical explicit formula of $\psi(x)$ and using the functional equation of $\zeta(s)$.